# Reusable tests in phpunit

Tags: phpunit, integration-testing

Suppose I want to test database consistency in three states:

1. When data have been inserted - I wanna make sure that certain amount of rows have been inserted to the database tables.
2. When data have been updated - I wanna repeat rows amount test (amount must be the same as after insert)
3. When data have been deleted - I wanna make sure that all data were deleted.

Also when I do insert or update, some files (images) could be uploaded to the server and file paths will be stored in the database. So I also would like to check that files amount corresponds with rows amount in database files table.

In other words i want to reuse two methods: `testRowsAmountOnAddUpdate` and `testFilesAmountOnAddUpdate` after insert and update.

What is the best way to organize my code? Should I use fixtures?

Comment: Normally, you would not worry about the actual database testing in your code, and mock the database calls.  This allows your code to continue as if the rows were added or not based on the return.  After all, you are testing your code, not the database.  However, when you want to test your library that interfaces with the database, then you want to make the checks you are talking about. There is a DBUnit extension to PHPUnit for just this, so you can work with the database in unit tests for your libraries.  IE: Do not load data into the DB to query and count records returned.

Comment: Let me explain the whole process I'm going through.
First of all - I'm using a php framework. The framework has ORM models which help me access data in the database. Also in the framework's settings stored DB connection settings. DB connection initialized in the framework source.

Comment: Second - I have an external data source. I'm downloading data from that source, parse it and apply to ORM models. At this point the difference between external source's data and local database's data could be described by 3 states: new rows comes from the external source - I should insert it to my DB, there are exists rows in the source - I should update rows in my DB (basically delete unrelevent and insert new ones), and if some rows exists in my local DB and they doesn't came from the source - I should delete them from my DB.
So I have the worker that do all that things.

Comment: Now, what I want to get from the tests is whether my worker handle all that states correctly. Whether expected amount of rows were inserted / updated / deleted. I also would like to check if described in the external source files (images) were succesefully uploaded (or deleted) and files amount corresponds with rows amount in the DB files table.

Comment: As I understood from DBUnit manual: I should setup and create connection to my DB, create fixtures with sample data (xml files), and that's not really what I want.
I want to test my worker behaviour in real world conditions. How it interacts with a real DB (or I can use production copy of the DB for tests). And I didn't quite understand why I can't load data to DB to query and count records?

Comment: You could use a duplicate of the production DB, but remember that data will change, and every time you add 1 record, the total count goes up. Even if you are doing the same small table, the record count will increase with each run of the same test, and date/time changes are not consistent either.  The reason most suggestions are to not test the framework is that it should have tests proving it works.  Then you can use the DB unit to do basic tests with the DBUnit restrictions.  Use the PHPUnit to ensure your code does everything to the framework correctly.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your answers! Now I understand why I should use `setUp` and `tearDown` methods. I will load test data in `setUp` and then return DB to the original state in `tearDown`. So it means that I need to use fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some comments have said, whenever possible, it's better to mock the database intarction layer, however sometimes you just have to test the interaction between code and database, espcially for complicated queries. I personally use this for database fixtures and assertions: (erm, disclaimer, I alsow rote this so I am biased)

https://github.com/malteriesch/test-db-acle

It allows to insert data in a pipe seperated tabular format, whilst inserting default values into any non-null columns and afterwards to inspect the state of the database.

```
$this->setupTables("
        [address]
        address_id  |company
        1           |me
        3           |you

        [user]
        user_id  |name
        10       |John
        20       |Mary

    ");
// excercise the SUT, e.g.
$this->addressService->addEntry("them");

$this->assertTableStateContains("
        [address]
        address_id  |company
        1           |me
        3           |you
        100         |them #this is the new row inserted

        [user]
        user_id  |name
        10       |John
        20       |Mary
        ");
}
```

Maybe you can wrap these in `testRowsAmountOnAddUpdate` and `testFilesAmountOnAddUpdate` , for the file upload I would read the value of the field and then assert that the file specified there exists.

Note that DBUnit is also a good way to go, personally I like to write tests as easily and concise as possible and only concentrate on the information that actually changes/is relevant in the test. Otherfixtures for me were just a little to verbose.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I've  came to this structure (code is simplyfied):

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

     private static $expectedRowsAmountInDB;

     private function getRowsAmountFromDB()
     {
           //using this method to get rows count from DB
     }

     public function setUp()
     {
          //import initial data, set up the world
     }

     public function testRowsAmountOnAdd()
     {
          //count rows amount after setup
          //using getRowsAmountFromDB helper method
          $this->assertEquals(self::$expectedRowsAmountInDB, $this->getRowsAmountFromDB());
     }

     public function testRowsAmountOnUpdate()
     {
          //...here comes update rows code
          $this->assertEquals(self::$expectedRowsAmountInDB, $this->getRowsAmountFromDB());
     }

     public function testRowsAmountOnDelete()
     {
          //...here comes delete rows code
          $this->assertEquals(self::$expectedRowsAmountInDB, $this->getRowsAmountFromDB());
     }

     public function tearDown()
     {
          //delete all rows that were created in this test
          //and back DB to the original state
     }


}
```